# Nginx regex rule for caching images override the root location block

Tags: nginx, configuration

My nginx setup contains the following location rules:

```
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
        expires 7d;
    }

    location /data/ {
            root /mnt/data;
    }
```

The problem is, when I try to access one of the following files (jpg | jpeg | png | gif | ico | css | js | pdf) in the /data/ folder I get 404 Not Found error, cause the first location rule overrides the second. I tried to do something like this:

```
    location ~* /data/.*\.jpg$ {
            root /mnt/data;
            expires 7d;
    }
```

But this doesn't seems to work. Could you please help me what solutions are available for me in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solutions are:

**#1 Rule duplication**

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
    expires 7d;
}

location /data/ {
    root /mnt/data;

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
        expires 7d;
    }
}
```

**#2 Symlink**

You can create a symlink: `$document_root/data -> /mnt/data`.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but in this scenario, the files located in /data/ won't be cached at all?

Comment: Well, no. `location ~*` has precendence, so `/data/image.jpg` will be served with `expires 7d;` from the `$root/data` directory, not the `/mnt/data`. Where are the assets located?

Comment: The data located on dedicated volume, mounted under /mnt/data/.

Comment: Sorry, I've misunderstood the problem.

Comment: That's okay, thank you very much for the solution!